# "Does not exist in the namespace" errors in XAML when project compiles fine

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

I keep getting XAML errors and "Invalid Markup" in design view when working with projects which compile and run just fine without any compiler or runtime errors.

Specifically the project I am trying to open is located here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474212/Zombie-Explorer-A-N-Tier-application-from-top-to-b

The issue seems to be with using classes in XAML from any external library which is not part of my source code, such as the Cinch and MahApps packages.  I've found in some cases I can add the package through the NuGet Package Manager and it will replace the reference and it sometimes fixes the error.

To be honest, I'm not sure there's a single XAML file I can open without errors, even some errors about unresolved references to resources in the same solution.

I have read that changing "maximum parallel project builds" to 1 can fix these types of issues, but I've tried that and get the same results.

**Is there any way to fix these errors so I can utilize the XAML designer?**

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code and am looking at it -- do you have a particular .xaml file that you have a question about?

In general, yes - it can be a bit of a trial to get the Designer (whether VS or Blend) to render your XAML composition without errors, when it does compile and run just fine. To troubleshoot this, you can debug the process of Visual Studio rendering it, itself, using another instance of Visual Studio. Or, the more laborious route, by stripping it down until no errors show, and then re-entering it until you see the errors reappear. I myself created a logger to log errors during rendering (within the VS Designer) to help me uncover what is different about it.

It is important to remember that the Designer has a very specific behavior in recreating your code as it parses and renders your xaml objects. It executes the code within the xaml itself. It will create the view-model objects, if your xaml has a binding expressed within the xaml that causes this. But, surprisingly, it does **not** execute the constructor of your main xaml object (such as a Window or UserControl). So if you're depending upon having an object exist so that it can be rendered, do the creating or initialization within code that does execute at design-time such as a property-getter or a bound property.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, though the "missing" class is in my own project.  I moved my project from a (mirrored) network drive to a local drive and that resolved it - suggesting that the problem is poor file management by VS.